# wavesurfer.js bug when using a scale on it

Tags: css, wavesurfer.js

I have this `waveform` and it's ok:

```js
const wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
     container: document.querySelector(`#waveform`),
     backend: 'MediaElement',
     waveColor: '#525054',
     progressColor: '#eb7100',
     cursorColor: 'transparent',
     height: 450,
     fillParent: true,
     minPxPerSec: 100,
     hideScrollbar: true,
});
wavesurfer.load(`https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3`);
```

```css
.container {
    width: 1536px;
    height: 864px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform-origin: center center;
    z-index: 1;
    /*The line below causes the error...*/
    transform: translate(-50%, -66.5px) scale(0.846065);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/2.0.4/wavesurfer.min.js" integrity="sha512-mhqErQ0f2UqnbsjgKpM96XfxVjVMnXpszEXKmnJk8467vR8h0MpiPauil8TKi5F5DldQGqNUO/XTyWbQku22LQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="waveform" class="waveform"></div>
</div>
```

If you click on the waveform to seek to special point, you'll see that the point you clicked and the point where the wave detects your click is different!!!

I found out that the issue is caused by `scaling` of the container here:

```
.container {
    ...
    transform: translate(-50%, -66.5px) scale(0.846065);
}
```

How can we fix this issue?

**Note:** I need the scaling of the container and ofcourse the values my be different ...

Here is a reproduction of the issue on codepen: https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/YzQONBY